# ui-router deeplinking and parent resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I really love ui-router, I am getting so much more structure into my application. This is the way to go!

I am running into an issue where my parent state needs to be resolved, before my 'child' state . From a top-down interaction (country > city) the resolves are working fine! From a deeplinking situation (#/country/city) things are a bit more difficult.

Is it possible to do async/callbacks stuff when needed? Like, in this case? Thanks!

Adriaan